# How to group files by date using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, file, grouping

I have a folder with 2000+ files. I want to count the files by date.

so with:

```
  Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name  
   ----                -------------     ------ ----  
   -a---        2010-03-15  12:54 AM   10364953 file1.txt  
   -a---        2010-03-15   1:07 AM   10650503 file2.txt  
   -a---        2010-03-16   1:20 AM   10118657 file3.txt  
   -a---        2010-03-16   1:33 AM    9735542 file4.txt  
   -a---        2010-03-18   1:46 AM   10666979 file5.txt
```

I'd like to see:

```
Date         Count
----------   ------
2010-03-15   2  
2010-03-16   2  
2010-03-18   1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Group-Object can handle this sort of chore pretty easily:

```
Get-ChildItem | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | Sort Name
```

If you only want to see the date and count tack on the Format-Table as shown below:

```
Get-ChildItem | Group {$_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} | Sort Name | 
    Format-Table Name,Count -auto
```

Comment: Ah, a one-liner, even better.

Comment: Side Note: `group { $_.LastWriteTime.Date }` works as well but returns the timestamp in the `Name` property as well (though set to `0:00:00`). That's likely why Keith uses a formatted string here instead (which confused me initially). Another option would be `Format-Table -GroupBy` which has a different output.

Comment: Plus the format string gets the date in the format Shane wanted.  :-).  Note that you have to be careful using Format-Table -GroupBy. If you use it, be sure to sort first on what you are grouping by otherwise you can wind up with the same "group" specified multiple times.

Comment: Be careful! `.ToString` works only with Powershell 7! With Powershell 5 you'll encounter nasty error messages! 

`Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hash table to collect the information you need:

```
     $dict = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Hashtable
     Get-ChildrenItem * | Where-Object { $dict[$_.lastwritetime.date]++ }
     $dict
```